# Scala pattern matching distinguishing path dependent types depends on scope instances defined in?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, path-dependent-type

**UPDATED: simplified code that runs in repl**

I want to create domain-specific events like Created, Updated, Deleted, etc using path-dependent types that extends a common marker trait so that domains can (a) send each other events and (b) pattern match by domain:

```
trait Event

trait Domain {
  case class Created(name: String) extends Event
}

// declare three instances of Domain trait, one here and two 
// in an inner scope

object DomainC extends Domain

{
   object DomainA extends Domain
   object DomainB extends Domain

   def lookingForAs(event: Event): Unit = {
      println(s"${event.getClass}")
      event match {
        case DomainB.Created(_) => println("Oops matched a B")
        case DomainC.Created(_) => println("Oops matched a C")
        case DomainA.Created(_) => println("Found my A")
      }
   }

   lookingForAs(DomainA.Created("I am an A"))
}
```

The result is "Oops matched a C"

The `lookingForAs` function

- *correctly* does not match instance of DomainA.Created to DomainB.Created
- *incorrectly* matches instance of DomainA.Created to DomainC.Created

Same result in REPLs for Scala 2.10.2, 2.10.3, 2.10.4 and 2.11.5

Comment: In which class is defined `lookingForAs` ?

Comment: I defined all the types in one object in the same file and  I get "Oops matched a B".

Comment: The above is wrapped in a unit test class except of course for RemoteDomain which is in another file in the same package.  I'll try same file/different enclosing object to see if that makes a difference

Comment: Printing `event.getClass` in `lookingForAs` prints simply `Domain$Created` for any origin of `event` for me. Does it print different things in your case?

Comment: OK some more detail -- moving the DomainA and DomainB declarations out of the scope of the unit test but within the same file causes "Oops matched a B" but moving them into the unit test gives "Found my A"

Comment: Printing `event.getClass` in `lookingForAs` prints `Domain$Created` for any origin of `event` and whether or not the `DomainA`/`DomainB` declarations are inside or outside of the unit test class

Comment: Completing the variations:
(1) both DomainA and DomainB declared INSIDE the unit test - "Found my A" GOOD
(2) both DomainA and DomainB declared OUTSIDE the unit test - "Oops ..."
(3) DomainA OUTSIDE and DomainB INSIDE the unit test - "Found my A"   GOOD??
(4) DomainA INSIDE and DomainB OUTSIDE the unit test - "Oops..."

Comment: I don't think the pattern matching is dependent of the origin of the case class. It simply parses the case class and sees if it matches. Thus, logically, both `DomainB.Created` and `DomainA.Created` lead to the same outcome.

Comment: Mik378, am I following if I take your comment to mean that the fact that the pattern matches isn't necessarily a reflection of the actual types? Interesting possibility but does it provide an answer as to why the matching succeeds or fails when A/B are declared in the various positions listed?

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from scala-users Google Group: Jason Zaugg (retronym) says this is a Scala bug and has created [SI-9110](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4265) to track it for a fix targeted to 2.12.  Thanks again, Jason